# How to enable/disable a button based on selection of checkbox in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have few checkboxes which are coming from ngFor. I have a button which is disabled onload.
If I select/unselect only other checkboxes(which are not selected), button will be enable.
If I unselect any selected checkbox button will be enable.
If I select back again selected checkboxes button will be disable. Here is the code below  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mthf93?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let testitem of testVar">
    <input type="checkbox"  [checked]= "testitem.checked" (change)="changeit(testitem)" class="example-margin"/>
{{testitem.name}}
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="disabled">Submit</button>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  testVar: any;
  disabled = true;
  name = "Angular";
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testVar = [
      { id: 1, name: "apple", checked: false },
      { id: 2, name: "banana", checked: true },
      { id: 3, name: "orange", checked: false }
    ];
  }

  changeit(testitem) {
    console.log(testitem.checked);
    if (testitem.checked == false) {
      this.disabled = false;
    } else {
      this.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion following requirement was elaborated:
Here main requirement is if you make any new change, button will only be enable.so that those new changes can be saved into DB by clicking the button.

Possible solution:
You have to get the initial state and the current state somehow. Probably you should use a formGroup and split the current form from the model and diff it with that. I Just hacked the requirement it into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eysswr?file=src/app/app.component.ts  - but in my opinion should you split your model from the form for this requirement. see

just checking the current element will never allow you to check if the button must be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here button should be disabled initially, when you uncheck  the checked checkboxes, button will be enable. apart from that every thing is fine

Comment: So  your question is, how to enable the button only with one checkbox? I don't get it, as you write checkboxes but initially there is only one checkbox enabled.

Are you probably only missing to set the model to checked correctly in the changeit method?

Comment: The checkboxes which are already checked, for them button will be disable once the checkboxes are uncheck and checked again, button will be enable if you keep the checked box unchecked, button will also enabled if you either check or uncheck other checkboxes which are not checked initially. But by default on page load  button will be disabled

Comment: So the desired behaviour would be:
`
checked box to uncheck and checked again -> disable button 
``
checked box to uncheck -> leave button as is
``
unchecked box to check -> enable button
``
unchecked box to check and uncheckagain -> enable button
``
Describes this the desired behaviour?

Comment: Here main requirement is if you make any new change, button will only be enable.so that those new changes can be saved into DB by clicking the button

Comment: Ok - then you have to get the initial state and the current state somehow. Probably you should use a formGroup and split the current form from the model and diff it with that. I Just hacked the requirement it into https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eysswr?file=src/app/app.component.ts - but in my opinion should you split your model from the form for this requirement.